# Mongo add timestamp field from existing date field

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I currently have a collection with documents like the following:

```
{ foo: 'bar', timeCreated: ISODate("2012-06-28T06:51:48.374Z") }
```

I would now like to add a `timestampCreated` key to the documents in this collection, to make querying by time easier.

I was able to add the new column with an `update` and `$set` operation, and set the timestamp value but I appears to be setting the current timestamp using this:

```
db.reports.update({}, { 
    $set : { 
        timestampCreated : new Timestamp(new Date('$.timeCreated'), 0) 
    } 
}, false, true);
```

I however have not been able to figure out a way to add this column and set it's value to the timestamp of the existing 'timeCreated' field.

Comment: So, what was the final query which did this? I am getting some errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a find for all the documents, limiting to just the id and timeCreated fields. Then loop over that and generate the timestampCreated value, and do an update on each.

Comment: Can I do this directly in the mongodb shell?

Comment: There is a forEach you can run on the cursor object. See this question for an example that almost matches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146452/mongodb-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-all-records-in-a-collection

Answer (score -1):

Use [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) which can accept [aggregate pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-many-method-agg-pipeline) (starting from MongoDB 4.2) and thus take advantage of the [`$toLong`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) operator which converts a Date into the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

Also use the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) query in the update [filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-many-filter) to limit only documents with the `timeCreated` field and of Date type:

```
db.reports.updateMany(
    { 'timeCreated': {
        '$exists': true,
        '$type': 9
    } },
    [
        { '$set': { 
            'timestampCreated': { '$toLong': '$timeCreated' } 
        } }
    ]
)
```