# Increment months to a date using an element attribute

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

Let’s say I have a collection of subscriptions as below:

```
{
    "id": "8SDQ8"
    "durationInMonths": 12,
    "startDate": {
        "$date": "2020-07-03T09:14:46.609Z",
    },
    "endDate": {
        "$date": "2021-07-03T09:14:46.609Z",
    }
}
```

How can I add $durationInMonths to a variable date without being forced to fetch $durationInMonths beforehand (which adds an inefficient network round trip)? Something like this:

```
const myDate = new Date();
const sub = await Subscription.findOneAndUpdate({
    id: '8SDQ8'
}, {
    $set: {
        startDate: myDate,
        endDate: {
            $addMonths(myDate, "$durationInMonths")
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo add timestamp field from existing date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336694/mongo-add-timestamp-field-from-existing-date-field)

Comment: Well, this works from the mongo shell, and I'm not even sure whether it saves the network round-trip there, but running this from a node.js env using mongoose does need a find operation beforehand

Answer (score 1):

Updated to calculate the end date in months:

```
db.Subscription.update(    
    {_id: "8SDQ8"
},
[
   { $set: { 
      startDate: myDate, 
      endDate: {$dateFromParts: { 
         'year' : { $year: myDate }, 
         'month' : {$add: [
                     { $month: myDate
                     },
                     "$duration"
                  ]
               }, 
         'day': { $dayOfMonth: myDate
               }
            }
         } 
      }
   }
]
)
```

This answer assumes you only care about the year, month, and day, but you could easily include more precise date/time info in your endDate if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks for participating, I explored this option already, unfortunately, this doesn't work as a subscription can't be rounded to 30 days a month. I basically need to be able to have exactly 12 months =  1 year to handle this.

Comment: Figuring out how to handle the dates will be an issue no matter how you write your query.  Perhaps storing your duration in days, weeks, or years would be a better option.

Comment: I see what you mean, and AFAIK, there is no "date processing methods" usable in update operations. Now I was wondering, if there would be some "out-of-the-box" solution like executing some js code on mongodb server... Storing the duration in days or week might indeed work, but changing the model would have too many side effects and is not an option.

Comment: Also even if this issue could not be properly solved today, I believe the question would still make sense, and might be handled in a further mongodb release

Comment: Thanks for pushing on this! I just learned something new.  I updated my answer above, so it calculates the end date using the duration in months.

Comment: It does work on mongodb shell, but not on mongoose, see [this gh issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9236)

Comment: Bummer.  MongoDB 4.2 added the ability to update with an aggregation pipeline.  I'm not in the loop on if/when Mongoose added the same functionality.

Comment: it's planned for next release apparently, I'll test and approve the answer when it does work !