# Java, MongoDB: how to insert into subdocument's empty array

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm doing a `loop-and-update`, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991994/5161995).

And I have an existing document with fields like so:

```
"field1" : {
    "field2" : []
}
```

With an empty array.

With `Java`, how do I put a document inside the empty array?

Doing this...

```
// BasicDBObject obj...
obj.put("field1.field2", 
           new BasicDBObject().append("a", "aa").append("b", "bb"));
```

I get an error that says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name field1.field2
```

In `JavaScript`, it's easy - you just do, like:

```
obj.field1.field2["a"] = "aa";
```

etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit messed up. You cannot use the `dot` notation in `Java`. You need to `create` and `embed` objects.

To generate the equivalent of:

```
{ "field1" : { "field2" : [ { "a" : "aa"} , { "b" : "bb"}]}}
```

you need to do the following operations,

```
BasicDBList list = new BasicDBList();
list.add(new BasicDBObject("a","aa"));
list.add(new BasicDBObject("b","bb"));

DBObject fieldTwo = new BasicDBObject("field2",list);

DBObject fieldOne = new BasicDBObject("field1",fieldTwo);
```

Similarly, to push something inside an existing `list` you need to,

```
  while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
  BasicDBObject fieldOne = (BasicDBObject)(obj.get("field1"));

  // get the list
  BasicDBList field2List = (BasicDBList)(fieldOne.get("field2"));

  // add something to it
  field2List.add(new BasicDBObject("a","aa"));
  list.add(new BasicDBObject("b","bb"));
  list.add(new BasicDBObject("c","cc"));


  //save it
  this.dataColl.save(obj);
  }
```

would give you,

```
{ "field1" : { "field2" : [ { "a" : "aa"} , { "b" : "bb"} , { "c" : "cc"}]}}
```

[`BasicDBObject`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) takes a key `name` and a `value` as its arguments.A `key` name cannot contain the `.` operator in it. That is why you get the error:

```
Invalid BSON field name field1.field2
```