# Need help to write a mongodb script that will generate a smaller and more useful collection from a large collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**documents in my current collection, let's call it original**

```
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "location" : [  "Dwarka" ] , "tags" : [  "Estate Agents For Residential",  "Estate Agents", "Agents For Residence"  ] }
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "location" : [  "Dwarka" ], "tags" : [  "Estate Agents For Residential",  "Estate Agents", "Commercial Rental" ]}
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "location" : [  "Dwarka" ],  "tags" : [  "Estate Agents For Residential",  "Estate Agents" ] }
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "location" : [  "South Extension" ], "tags" : [  "Estate Agents For Residence" ] }
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "location" : [  "Greater Kailash II" ], "tags" : [  "Estate Agents For Residence" ] }
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "location" : [  "Greater Kailash II" ], "tags" : [  "Estate Agents For Rental" ] }
```

**The first collection I want to generate from the original collection, lets call it city-locations**

```
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "locations" : [  "Dwarka", "South Extension", "Greater Kailash II" ] }
```

**The second collection I want to generate from the original collection, lets call it city-location-tags**

```
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "location" : [  "Dwarka" ], "tags" : [  "Estate Agents For Residential",  "Estate Agents", "Agents For Residence", "Commercial Rental"   ] }
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "location" : [  "South Extension" ], "tags" : [  "Estate Agents For Residence" ]}
{ "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "location" : [  "Greater Kailash II" ], "tags" : [  "Estate Agents For Residence", "Estate Agents For Rental"  ] }
```

**My challenge:**
My original collection has more than a million documents and fetching all locations for a selected city and fetching all the tags from a selected city & locations to populate related dropdowns is taking a long time. By creating smaller collections I am trying to achieve faster response time. In my project, when a user selects a city from a dropdown I have to show all the available locations for the selected city in the next dropdown and after the location is selected I have to show all the available tags for that location+city in the next dropdown and this has to happen fast.

Thank you for your help

Comment: DO you have indexes set up?

Comment: I would recommend using the map-reduce built-in functionality of MongoDB.

Comment: Dear @AlexTheedom I have index created on city, location and tags but its not helping much with response time thats the reason I want to create 2 more separate collections that would be much smaller in size compared to the original.

Comment: Dear @AndreiNicusan, I am new to mongodbd world. Would appreciate your help with the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I offer a correction to @Jinxcat's answer. The result of running the aggregation leaves the city field blank because there is no city field in the group/addToSet aggregation results. The city data is located in the _id field. Therefore in the final $project aggregation the reference to _id.city is irrelevant and should refer to only _id.

```
db.india.aggregate([
  {$group:      {_id:{city:"$city", location:"$location"}}},
  {$project:    {_id:0, city: "$_id.city", location:"$_id.location"}},
  {$group :     {_id:"$city", locations: {$addToSet: "$location"}} },
  {$project:    {_id:0, city: "$_id", locations: "$locations"} }
])
```

The edit in bold changed: {$project: {_id:0, city: **"$_id"**, locations: "$locations"} }

Comment: @Alex this works perfect and returns exactly what is expected. Thanks for your help. How should I go about the second collection cityLocationTags?

Comment: @Kumar Deepam Done it. See my response below.

Comment: @AlexTheedom thanks a ton! Will try it and update you how it went. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. If you are happy with my answer can you accept it. Thanks and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by use of the aggregation framework. Complete reference can be found at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

Your first resultset can be created by something like the following:

```
db.original.aggregate([
{$group :  {_id: {city:"$city", location:"$location"} } },
{$project: {_id:0, city: "$_id.city", location: "$_id.location"} },
{$unwind: "$location"},
{$group :  {_id: "$city", locations: { $addToSet: "$location"} } },
{$project: {_id:0, city: "$_id", locations: "$locations"} }
])
```

Your second resultset cat be created by the following:

```
db.original.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$tags"},
{$group: { _id: { city:"$city", location:"$location"}, tags: { $addToSet: "$tags" }  } },
{$project: { _id:0, city:"$_id.city", location:"$_id.location", tags:"$tags" } }
])
```

I am however sceptical as to if you need to create different collections, as they would then need to be deleted and recreated every time you have an update in the original collection. Caching the results for each city (especially in the second case) would make much more sense, and you can invalidate the key whenever you have an update.

Also, why do you want to have one-element lists (city, location) in your results?

Comment: Thanks @Jinxcat! As mentioned by @Alex Theedom the city was coming empty. Also, this query is returning a new document for every location of a city. In my case, i was looking for the doc to be in this format { "city" : [  "Delhi" ], "locations" : [  "Dwarka", "South Extension", "Greater Kailash II" ] } Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ammended to fix mistake in projection and have locations in a list of items instead of a list of 1-item lists. Please let me know if I am missing anything else

Comment: Now locations come properly in a list of items but the city is still empty. See this output doc for example { "_id" : ObjectId("52ebc7497d5b6db89da7dfec"), "locations" : [  "Baramati HO",  "Baramati",  "Malegaon Bk",  "Baramati Ho",  "Kasba " ], "city" : [ ] }

Comment: Edited: city: "$_id.city"   -> city: "$_id"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple command if you change the city to be a json value instead of an json array because the _id of the aggregated collection cannot be an array. Do you really need the city to be an array in the original document?

The way you can do it is as follows:

```
var cityLocations = db.original.aggregate({$group : {_id:"$city", locations: {$addToSet: "$location"}}});
db.createCollection("cityLocations");
db.cityLocations.insert(cityLocations.result);
```

You can similarly group it for city-location-tags as well. Look at the [Aggregation commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/nav-aggregation/)

Comment: Dear @Saket, thanks a lot for your answer, I wouldn't mind city to be json value but I already have it as json array. Is there a way that I can change it to be json value on the existing collection? The original collection has 1M+ documents and I'm not sure how to change the city to be json value. Would really appreciate your help to get me going with this. Thanks

Comment: db.original2.save(db.original.find().map(function(u){u.city=u.city[0];return u})); will save it to a different collection original2.

Comment: You can also look at the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146452/mongodb-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-all-records-in-a-collection

Comment: This query is failing, saying Assertion failed... db.original2.save(db.original.find().map(function(u){u.city=u.city[0];return u}));

Comment: Have you created another collection called original2?

Comment: my bad. I will create and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Kumar Deepam this should produce the second set with the keys in the right order: City, Location and Tags.

```
db.india.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$city"}, {$unwind : "$location"}, {$unwind : "$tags"},
    {$group:      {_id:{city : "$city", location :"$location"}, tags : {$addToSet:"$tags"}}},
    {$group:      {_id:{city : "$_id.city", location : "$_id.location", tags : "$tags"}}},
    {$project:    {_id:0, city : "$_id.city", location : "$_id.location", tags : "$_id.tags"}}
])
```

Its longer than @Jinxcat's answer but if its important to have the keys in the right order then this should do the job.

BTW I wonder if its possible to optimise this aggregation? Anyone got any ideas? Thanks All.