# Mongoose : Update large amount of data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bigdata

So, here's my problem. I have two collections (coll1, coll2) full of about 1.5 millions of documents with the same fields. They have more than 95% of docs in common but some coll1 docs have email filled not null and coll2 have more documents.

The final collections I want is the coll2 but with the emails of coll1.

Here how I am doing :

```
 const options = {
  socketTimeoutMS: 0,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 30,
};
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/coll1`, options);

const Coll1Model = mongoose.model(coll, collSchema);

Coll1Model.find({ email: { $ne: '' } })
  .select({ id: 1, email: 1, _id: 0 })
  .then((result) => {
    const Coll2Model = mongoose.model(coll2, collSchema);

    const bulk = Coll2Model.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    // c is about 390k
    const c = result.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < c; i += 1) {
      bulk.find({ id: result[i].id }).updateOne({ $set: { email: result[i].email } });
    }
    bulk
      .execute()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log('End', new Date());
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('End', new Date());
      });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error', err);
  });
```

The problem I have with this is that it is way too long and way too resource consuming (about 1h30 for 20% with the cpu between 60 and 80%)

I am far of an expert about MongoDB and mongoose so if someone has an idea to do that a better way I would be happy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - what is the fastest way to update all records in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146452/mongodb-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-all-records-in-a-collection)

Comment: I tried this : jsfiddle.net/5aj6j10m and execute it via : mongo mydb update.js but it's still way too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to reduce the time from 4-5 hours to like 2-3 minutes with indexes.

```
db.coll2.createIndex({id: 1}, function(err, col) {
  var bulk = db.coll2.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

  db.coll1.find({ email: { $ne: '' } }).forEach(function(data) {
    bulk.find({ id: data.id }).updateOne({ $set: { email: data.email } 
    });
  });

  bulk.execute();
}
```

Executed in command line : mongo mydb update.js